# Display message button on other users' profile

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to display a message button on other users' profile but not on my profile after I login in a Django website. I can check the user authentication by

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

But how to check if the user is not the one on the profile and then display the message button? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user you are logged in as is usually available as `request.user`, whereas it is your job to making the user of the profile you are viewing available to the template. Assuming your profile has a foreign key to the user, you can do something like this:

```
 {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user != profile.user %}
```

Alternatively, you could move this logic into your view or create a custom template tag.